# element loaded in dom but element not clickable - Selenium

Tags: angular, selenium, webdriver, protractor, automated-tests

I have a page that has a table with the checkbox in the first column. The table loads 25 rows by default and 25 rows additionally on scrolling. I have used below code to get 25 checkboxes loaded on default and click on them:

```
List<WebElement> checkboxes = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//input[@type='checkbox']"));
    for(WebElement checkbox : checkboxes){
        checkbox.click();
    }
```

When I look at the browser while executing, it clicks the checkbox that is currently fit to screen (8 checkboxes) and for the 9th checkbox, it throws element not clickable at the moment exception. When I run the code in debug mode and execute click after scrolling the rows in the browser, the code runs ok.
Please let me knot how do I solve this issue.

P.S. The webpage is made using angular 5. I also tried the same thing using Protractor and the issue exists there as well.

Comment: Please show a screenshot of your table in Angularjs 5 page so that we can see it has self scrollbar or not, if it has and the 9th row is visible in default,  you no need to scroll it.  And give screenshot of another table in JSP

Answer (score 0):

You can scroll to every checkbox and click on it.

Please ref below code

```
 List<WebElement> checkboxes = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//input[@type='checkbox']"));
        for(WebElement checkbox : checkboxes){

    ((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript(“arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);”, checkbox );
            checkbox.click();
        }
```

or you can try below code to scroll

```
public static void scrollToElement(WebElement element){
Point point = element.getLocation();
logger.info("X cord "+point.getX()+"y cord "+point.getY());
scroll(point.getX(), point.getY());
```

}

Comment: didn't work. Now it gives an error for the element that is in the view also. I worked in a website that was made using JSF and had similar DOM but I never faced this issue. Do you know any reason why I am seeing this issue in an Angular site.

Comment: same error. element not clickable at the moment for the first checkbox as well

Comment: try to add explicit wait before click.. Can you please share your url ?

Comment: did not work with explicit wait as well. I cannot provide you the URL as it is not hosted anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

**Here is a workaround ...**

```
    List<WebElement> checkboxes = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//input[@type='checkbox']"));
    for(WebElement checkbox : checkboxes){
        try{
                checkbox.click();
        }catch(Exception e){
            JavascriptExecutor executer = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
            executer.executeScript("scroll(0, 250)");
            checkbox.click();
        }
    }
```

Hope this should work for you !

Comment: Do you know why I have to scroll before click? I didn't have to scroll before when my application was in JSP.